# Android custom popup dialog

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, popup, customdialog

How to make a custom dialog which can be customized like an image? Using dialog fragment we can make custom dialog. How to customize it more and make it flexible. I refer [here](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/)

[image: Custom dialog example]

Answer (score 0):

Use dialog fragments. This post from the google development blog will give u an idea.
Here is the [link](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html)

Comment: Yes it may be possible with DialogFragments but what I wonder which is the best practice to go with Dialog or Dialog themed Activity.

Comment: Creating an activity themed as a dialog is not a good practice. I personally feel dialog fragment is the way to go and give's u enough flexibility to create fully custom UI.